# if is not checking firebase reference to show and hide buttons

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question is making only the first if button visible, he is not checking whether or not he has it node casino. I have two accounts shown in the image one with the casino node and the other without. but the button opencasino is showing for both. in debug I can see that you are looking for the current user. but the result of the first "if" is the same for both accounts. can anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

code

```
 final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final String userId = user.getUid();


    ref.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {



                if (ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).equalTo("cassino") != null) {

                    openCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buyCassino.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } if  (ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).equalTo("cassino") == null ) {
                    buyCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    openCassino.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }



            }
        }
```

same problem using if else

```
ref.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {



            if (ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).equalTo("cassino") != null)  {
                openCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buyCassino.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else   {
                buyCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                openCassino.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }



        }
    }
```

DEBUG IMG
[image]

Comment: Is your if logic within your for loop evaluating to the correct case? This will help tell if this is an android lifecycle/draw issue or a firebase issue. Also, why if(!null) followed by if(null) why not use an else statement?

Comment: I tried but using "if" "else" the same thing happens. follow the code ...
check my update for a post. thanks for your reply

Comment: That still doesn't tell me if these statements are evaluating correctly or not. Does ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).equalTo("cassino") return a value here? If so, is this view within like a recycler view or anything like that?

Comment: in case it returns true! = it will display the opencasino button. if false returns the buycassino button. but it is not doing the checking it just checks the first "if" based on that makes the button visible. but without checking the firebase reference.

Comment: being clearer. if the casino node exists, display the opencasino button. if you do not have the casino node display the buycassino button.

Comment: Wait, why are you checking `ref` and not `ds` are you not checking the data you're getting from your listener?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210340/discussion-between-garrett-manley-and-upz91).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're checking the value from your database reference as opposed the DataSnapshot that your listener is returning in `onDataChange()`

Something like the below appears to be more what you're looking for, although the for loop itself may not be needed looking at the way your code is written.

```java
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
  if (ds.child("cassino").exists())  {
    openCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    buyCassino.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  } else {
    buyCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    openCassino.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```

---

#### Additional Notes

You may want to decouple your database logic from your visibility logic; unless of course it's just written this way for simplicity of articulating your issue.

Comment: hello thanks for your reply. using the account that has the casino node it does not display the opencasino. I did the debug and the uid and the casino node is loaded for the current user but it still shows buycassino that is in the "else". would you know tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Hello, I updated the question with the debug image. thank you for the patience.

Comment: hello thanks for your reply. I believe that the problem will now be the subject of a new question. thanks for your help.